# How does a Google App Engine app migrate to the new REGION_ID?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, url-routing, region

According to [Google's App Engine release notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/release-notes#February_11_2020) starting Feb 11, 2020 new App Engine applications will have a new REGION_ID within the app's URL like this: `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com`. They also state "This new URL is optional for existing apps, and will soon be required for all new apps."

In my case I have an existing app that has been assigned a new region by Google. Before February users and other websites have been accessing the app as `https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`.  When I recently deployed an update to the app, it reported that the new URL would be `https://PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com`. This seems to have two migration problems:

1. I now have two copies of the app, an old version at the old URL `https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com` that users are accessing but I can no longer update, and the latest version at the new URL `https://PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com`.
2. Since the region is assigned by Google, it's not clear that `https://PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com` will be a static URL I can reference.

How do I migrate users to the new app version given that they're using to the old URL? I don't see a way to update the old app version so I can redirect requests to the new app's URL. Also, should I expect to chase Google if they update my app's region from time to time, or possibly deploy it in more than one region?

Answer (score 1):

Your app has not been moved to another `REGION_ID`, the only change that has been made is that now the region is shown in the URL for App Engine. You can check that by running:

`gcloud app describe`

Running the above command will show you the description of your app and one of the fields is the region your application is running on. In the new format, `https://PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com` the letters located between `PROJECT_ID` and `r`, that in your case are `uc`, are a mapping that Google did to identify the region.

Until further notice, both URLs will be usable, and in case the older gets deprecated, they will send an email to all project owners so they are notified about this change and how the migration process should be done.

As for now, if you deploy more versions to your default service, all will be serving in both URLs:

- `https://PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com`
- `https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`

In case you deploy more services, those will have a slightly different notation:

- `https://service-dot-PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com`
- `https://service-dot-PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com`

Comment: Thanks. To my 2nd point, it's not clear how the REGION_ID is assigned (`uc` in my case). Is that going to be static or will the URL change again in the future? It appears from your comment that the URL without the REGION_ID could go away at some point, so I need to make sure users can always reach the app.

Comment: When the change was introduced, all the regions were assigned a code, in this case yours equals to `uc` and this is not going to change in the future. As your app belongs to a region and as for now there's no such option to change GAE's region, the URL won't change either.
The best move from now on would be using the URL with the region included as it's the newest and it's quite likely that Google is moving towards the usage of those.
TL;DR: Both URLs allow users to reach your app without any issue at all, although it is advised to use the one containing the `REGION_ID`.

Comment: This is not the case for me. I have an app deployed at `PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`. I just deployed new version. `PROJECT_ID.appspot.com` is still running the old version, while `PROJECT_ID.uc.r.appspot.com` is running the new version.